# How do I send data from Pub/Sub to Google Cloud Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm setting up a dataflow in Google Cloud Platform. I have retrieved data from IoT devices and sent to Pub/Sub, and I now want to store in Firestore. I am using Firebase for my web app where data should be displayed etc.

I realise this should be a simple task, but am still not finding too much information about it (probably too straight forward). Have looked at using Cloud Functions to retrieve from Pub/Sub and add to Firestore, which ought to work (although I got stuck at credentials), but is there an easier way that I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your thinking on using Cloud Functions as the recipient of a PubSub message coming from Cloud IoT Core and in that Cloud Function performing an insert into Firestore is exactly correct.

Here is an example showing just that:

https://blog.usejournal.com/build-a-weather-station-with-google-cloud-iot-cloud-firestore-mongoose-os-android-jetpack-350556d7a

If we Google search using "gcp pubsub firestore" we will find many others.

If you use this technique and run into puzzles/problems, don't hesitate to raise new questions (but first search and see if they have been raised before).  In your new questions, please be as detailed as possible.  There are many samples available for all sorts of related areas.  Have a study of these.